# Ask for amount of questions in list of list retrieved from a file

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm practising data processing of a survey of 3 people for 21 questions. I have a list from an outside file that I'm converting into a list of lists to count number of people that answered and number of questions inside the list ignoring the name. When I ran it, it shows 0. Its in 2 separate lists because I don't know how to fuse the 2 together.

eg.List is called name;

My attempt:

```
name=[A 012,B 345,C 678]
def listolists(name):
    res=[]
    for i in name:
        list2=i.split(',')
        res.append(list2)
    return (res)

listoname=listolists(name)

def numques(listoname):
    res=0
    for i in range (1,len(listoname[0])):
        res+=len(listoname)
    return res

print(numques(listoname))
```

Should show 3 people since A,B,C and 3 questions for 0,1,2

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is, and the input data is missing. Please make a [mre]. If you want more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: beside the point, but you could simplify `listolists` as a comprehension: `res = [i.split(',') for i in name]`

Comment: what do you mean by input data? if you mean the .txt then I used the list called name to represent it in the inquiry. The problem is how to show 0,1,2 is 3 questions when its in a list of lists format.

Comment: Yes, the .txt. That list is not valid Python syntax, so it doesn't help.

Comment: fixed in 'my attempt' to better reflect the given example.

Comment: @wjandrea how to incorporate simplification of listolists into function?In which line would i incorporate it?

Comment: `name` is not a valid list. Please post your actual input data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203360/discussion-between-admiral-pyro-and-wjandrea).